# Problem with calling export class in angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript

I am doing an application and new with Angular. I am currently using Angular 8. Here is my problem.

I have a shared model named "export class Client". This model is located on a src/app/shared folder with file name client.model.ts. Below is the sample code.

```
export class Client {
ClientID: number;
ClientName: string;
}
```

I need to call this Client class to my client.component.ts located on src/app/client folder.

I am having error on the code snippet below:

```
public client_: Client;

loadData() {
    this.service.getClient().subscribe(result => {
      this.client_ = result;
      console.table(result);
    }, error => console.error(error));}

url = '';
  onSelectFile(event) {
    if (event.target.files && event.target.files[0]) {
      var reader = new FileReader();

      reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]); // read file as data url

      reader.onload = (event) => { // called once readAsDataURL is completed
        this.url = event.target.result;
      }
    }
  }
```

The error message below

```
chunk {main} main-es2015.js, main-es2015.js.map (main) 643 bytes [initial] [rendered]
chunk {polyfills} polyfills-es2015.js, polyfills-es2015.js.map (polyfills) 122 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {runtime} runtime-es2015.js, runtime-es2015.js.map (runtime) 6.09 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {scripts} scripts.js, scripts.js.map (scripts) 229 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {styles} styles-es2015.js, styles-es2015.js.map (styles) 1.15 MB [initial] [rendered]
Date: 2019-07-06T07:51:36.380Z - Hash: 976b4a15d221c24ffe40 - Time: 6641ms

ERROR in src/app/client/client.component.ts:73:7 - error TS2696: The 'Object' type is assignable to very few other types. Did you mean to use the 'any' type instead?
  Type 'Object' is missing the following properties from type 'Client': ClientID, ClientName, Acronym, ContactPerson1, and 16 more.

73       this.client_ = result;
         ~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/app/client/client.component.ts:132:33 - error TS2339: Property 'result' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'.

132         this.url = event.target.result;
                                ~~~~~~
```

Below is the complete code of the two files.

for Client.Model.ts file

```
export class Client {

  ClientID: number;
  ClientName: string;
  Acronym: string;
  ContactPerson1: string;
  ContactEmail1: string;
  ContactNumber1: string;
  ContactPerson2: string;
  ContactEmail2: string;
  ContactNumber2: string;
  Address: string;
  StateProvince: string;
  Zip: string;
  Country: string;
  AvailElection: boolean;
  AvailSurvey: boolean;
  Logo: string;
  CopyrightText: string;
  Active: boolean;
  Modified: Date;
  LastModified: string;
}
```

For Client.Component.ts file

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, TemplateRef } from '@angular/core';
import { ClientService } from '../shared/client.service';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { Client } from '../shared/client.model';
import { BsModalService, BsModalRef } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-client',
  templateUrl: './client.component.html',
  styles: []
})

export class ClientComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    private service: ClientService,
    private modalService: BsModalService
  ) { }

  public client_: Client;

  modalRef: BsModalRef;
  @ViewChild('template', {static : true}) modal: TemplateRef<any>;

  showModal(clientData: Client) {
    if (clientData != null) this.populate(clientData);
    this.modalRef = this.modalService.show(this.modal, { class: 'modal-lg' });
  }

  hideModal(id) {
    this.modalService.hide(1);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loadData();
    this.resetForm();
  }

  populate(clientData: Client) {
    this.service.formData = Object.assign({}, clientData);
  }

  resetForm(form?: NgForm) {
    if(form!=null)
      form.resetForm();
    this.service.formData = {
      ClientID: 0,
      ClientName: '',
      Acronym: '',
      ContactPerson1: '',
      ContactEmail1: '',
      ContactNumber1: '',
      ContactPerson2: '',
      ContactEmail2: '',
      ContactNumber2: '',
      Address: '',
      StateProvince: '',
      Zip: '',
      Country: '',
      AvailElection: false,
      AvailSurvey: false,
      Logo: '',
      CopyrightText: '',
      Active: false,
      Modified: null,
      LastModified: ''
    };
  }

  loadData() {
    this.service.getClient().subscribe(result => {
      this.client_ = result;
      console.table(result);
    }, error => console.error(error));
  }

  onSubmit(form: NgForm) {
    if (form.value.ClientID == 0) {
      this.insert(form);
    }
    else {
      this.update(form);
    }    
  }

  insert(form: NgForm) {
    this.service.postClient(form.value).subscribe(res => {
        this.resetForm(form);
        this.loadData();
        this.modalService.hide(1);
      },
      err => {
        console.log(err);
      }
    )
  }

  update(form: NgForm) {
    this.service.putClient(form.value).subscribe(res => {
      this.resetForm(form);
      this.loadData();
      this.modalService.hide(1);
    },
      err => {
        console.log(err);
      }
    )
  }

  delete(ClientID: number, form: NgForm) {
    this.service.deleteClient(ClientID).subscribe(res => {
      this.resetForm(form);
      this.loadData();
      this.modalService.hide(1);
    },
      err => {
        console.log(err);
      }
    )
  }

  //upload (pending)
  url = '';
  onSelectFile(event) {
    if (event.target.files && event.target.files[0]) {
      var reader = new FileReader();

      reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]); // read file as data url

      reader.onload = (event) => { // called once readAsDataURL is completed
        this.url = event.target.result;
      }
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Typescript is strict regarding the data type that's why you're getting this error

```
 The 'Object' type is assignable to very few other types. Did you mean to use the 'any' type instead?
  Type 'Object' is missing the following properties from type 'Client': ClientID, ClientName, Acronym, ContactPerson1, and 16 more.
```

Angular is complaining because you declare a variable `public client_: Client;`, and it is expecting to have a value that conforms with the `Client` type.

You're `populate` function should be something like this

```
 populate(clientData: Client) {
       // don't use Object.assign(...) anymore. clientData is already a Client type
    this.service.formData = clientData;
  }
```

And `loadData` should be something like

```
loadData() {
    this.service.getClient().subscribe(result: Client => {
      this.client_ = result;
      console.table(result);
    }, error => console.error(error));
  }
```

The change here is that you add a type in your `result` variable. Without this, result could be any data type.

Lastly, you need to change how you return the data in your `ClientService` and make sure that you're `getClient` variable is returning a `Client` data type so it should be something like this

```
getClient():Client {
....
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: adding "Client" on this.service.getClient().subscribe(result : Client => gives me this Cannot find name 'result'.

Comment: its also giving me this error. ERROR in src/app/client/client.component.ts:75:46 - error TS1005: ',' expected.

75     this.service.getClient().subscribe(result: Client => {

Comment: Adding Client to result only gives it a data type. So result should still be accessible. Can you provide a sample in stackblitz?

Comment: here's the editor https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4g4wtb. i just created client and shared folders under src/app folder and the files associated with the problem

Comment: @DevGeek pls make sure that the stackblitz created is properly configured similar on your local machine. Not just copy pasting code

Comment: okay got it. i just need to go somewhere. i will inform you once everything is in place in stackblitz repo